# i want to know how to tracing a exe's http responses and log them

Tags: windows, debugging

I want to "crack" this cheat loader protected by thermedia and I had someone do it before but lost contact with them and, now I would like to learn to do it myself. and they said a basic way to do it would just to trace their http responses and "log" them can't really find many articles on this so I'm asking if anyone is willing to give me a helping hand and maybe show me some stuff or point me in the right direction

Comment: Given it uses HTTP (insecure connection) you can use network traffic analysis tools such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to log the packets and inspect their payloads; in case it's HTTPS (encrypted traffic), you need to bypass [SSL/TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) encryption first

Comment: hey mimak could you check your email i sent you one going more in depth asking some questions